# VS 2008, Profiling Multiple Tests

Tags: visual-studio, performance, unit-testing

I have written a set of acceptance tests, and am trying to test the performance of a library with them.  Unfortunately, I can only seem to select a single test and "Create Performance Session" ...which doesn't give a true picture of performance of the app as a whole.

Is there a way to get a performance report of all the tests at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio Team Test or Team Suite, you should be able to create a **Load Test**, which looks like a single test, but can encapsulate as many unit tests as you want.

Since the Load Test is only a single test, you may be able to create a Performance Session for it. However, if you just need some performance statistics, the Load Test should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own test runner. Should not be too difficult depending on the testing frame work you are using. You can then profile the test runner.

Comment: There has to be a better solution than rolling my own test runner.  Somebody has to have done this already.

Comment: Really? Just develop your own testing framework runner. Why not reengineer the language too....

Comment: Are you comparing the design of a language with writing a test runner? There is a tutorial over on codeproject (search for "advanced unit testing"). Also most unit testing frame works are open source...

Comment: I guess you are not really understanding the problem here. All the runner needs to do is find and run all the tests. There is no need for evaluation. Just calling a bunch of methods. That's it. Nothing unlikely about it.